# Are regression question unwelcome on M.SE? What are the requirements if they are?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I was wondering if M.SE was the right place to ask regression questions.

Indeed sometimes One can ask regression question and get bright answers like  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1489414/why-is-r2-rho2) when he would'nt have no answers  on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) (which is less known, I know).

Sometimes as far as some users are not used to the lesat square model in regression for instance, with his hypotheses and assumptions (what are ESS, RSS if the variables are independant...), some other users put it on hold as unclear.

As far as there is already at least 800 questions on MS.E but still question left as unclear or doesn't have much attention like [here, a clear and easy question asked several month ago with few views](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1160405/regression-model-find-vary-i-hat-y-i), I was wondering what where the requirements to ask regression question and if they were welcome on M.SE.

Comment: Of course regression questions are on topic. But maybe most users here say [Non, je ne régresse rien](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q3Kvu6Kgp88) - and then [stats.se] could be the better place for such questions.

Comment: @Marine1 As a context for this question, you might want to link to your recent question on main which apparently caused the present post, so that everybody can see the lack of mathematical context you seem to be happy with in your questions on main, even after commenters ask you to add some.

Comment: @Did, sorry I deleted my happy question but copied and past it as it was to the happy cross validated where it obtained an happy answer!
Made the world a better place today... Maybe you should listen to a bit of Piaf, by the way...

Comment: Deleting questions after they received reactions as comments, even if these do not quite suit you, is stating that these reactions count for nothing. Re "happiness" on CV, are you alluding to the question commented as "This question cannot be answer(ed) without more details, about the model and about your notations", to the one which received an offtopic answer, or the one closed as duplicate and commented as "the question is wrong in the first place"? (I see no other, are there?) Re "happiness", getting even moderately informed about what Piaf's actual life was, could allow you to reconsider.

Comment: @Did, wathever may the question your alluding to, I got my answers! You pay too much attention to what others may think of you, my dear. And actually I was not talking about Piaf s life, but to listen to a bit of Piaf, which would maybe leads you to regression, (or, enventually, to enjoy life like was the $1^{er}$REP the day they regressed). Reconsider!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. "Question about X are welcome" does not mean "questions about X get answered often".
2. Stats site has fewer users overall, but those interested in answering statistics questions tend to know it and use it.

Compare the numbers:

Regression questions on [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/regression/topusers):

[image: math]

Regression questions on [Stats](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/regression/topusers):

[image: stats]